# ipv6 network unreachable

Tags: networking, ipv6

Some strange problem here, I have got an ipv6 address by DHCP, however, ping ipv6.google.com gets network unreachable. Other people in the same house using windows7 has ipv6 working fine. So, there seems to exists some mistake in my ubuntu configuration. BTW, there is vmware installed in my computer, and my windows7 in vmware can also get ipv6 address and work fine (using bridged network).

I will give some informations here.

ifconfig -a eth0

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:22:de:5b:50  
          inet addr:114.212.203.128  Bcast:114.212.207.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:da8:1007:4001::3:373d/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:22ff:fede:5b50/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:87348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:3
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52280256 (52.2 MB)  TX bytes:15413471 (15.4 MB)
```

ping6 -I eth0 2404:6800:4005:805::100e

```
PING 2404:6800:4005:805::100e(2404:6800:4005:805::100e) from 2001:da8:1007:4001::3:373d eth0: 56 data bytes
From 2001:da8:1007:4001::3:373d icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2001:da8:1007:4001::3:373d icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2001:da8:1007:4001::3:373d icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2001:da8:1007:4001::3:373d icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
^C
--- 2404:6800:4005:805::100e ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4999ms
```

ip -6 route

```
2001:da8:1007:4001::3:373d dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev vmnet1  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev vmnet8  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via fe80::da49:bff:fe91:e98f dev eth0  proto static  metric 1 
default via fe80::da49:bff:fe91:e98f dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 380sec
```

ip -6 neigh

```
fe80::da49:bff:fe91:e98f dev eth0  router INCOMPLETE
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback
```

So, does any one has ideas?

Comment: The INCOMPLETE neighbour discovery is the problem. If you can't talk to your router then all communication ends (especially because you have your IPv6 address configured as a /128, so you don't have a local subnet (usually a /64) to talk to). This might be because of some strange multicast filtering as IPv6 Neighbour Discovery uses ethernet multicast.

Comment: Because I see that the default gateway address is (also) learned through Router Advertisements I am assuming that that address is ok

Comment: And of course: check your `ip6tables` settings. You might be filtering ND traffic by accident

Comment: The ubuntu system is fresh installed. So there is no change in ip6tables settings. And, since it's a fresh install, it won't take much effort to do another fresh install. I just reinstall ubuntu system and the problem is solved. I don't know why, but I get a new ipv6 address and now everything is ok.

Comment: @SanderSteffann The /128 thing seems to be a red herring. DHCPv6 does that to me, too, but the default route is via the link-local address, so it doesn't seem to matter much.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know, it does work. However, if you don't have a /64 route for the local subnet everything is off-link and even local traffic has to go through the default gateway. If that default gateway is unreachable you lose all...

Comment: Now I get ipv6 address `2001:da8:1007:4001::3:4e3d/128` and neigh `fe80::da49:bff:fe91:e98f dev eth0 lladdr d8:49:0b:91:e9:8f router REACHABLE`. So I think the problem lies in the router.